# Exception while trying to connect JSON Server

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, crud

I am currently working on a CRUD android app for homework, and I am getting an strange problem that doesn't happen on the example provided by the teacher.

We are working with Docker JSON Server and we are adding data to that server, but there is an error when I click the button to go to the activity.

I will paste the logcat next:

[image]

And is caused by: 
[image]

Next i'm copying the java class "Cliente" which is causing the error:

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Cliente {
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:3000/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit obtenerCliente(){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And then, the line 80 on ActivityPokemones:

```
retrofit = Cliente.obtenerCliente();
```

I don't really know which is the problem, but i'm not having that problem on the example given by the teacher and it's almost a copy&paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Case 1

If You Are Using the Emulator:

***The bad news first: this solution only work with the emulator and not with your actual devices.***

1. Start up your emulator (since it could take a while until it is ready)
2. Start your server at localhost and attach the debugger
3. Change the API endpoints in your Android code to http://10.0.2.2 (*This reroutes the requests from your emulator to your computer’s localhost*)
4. Run the Android app on the emulator and cause the requests you want to debug

This should enable you to catch the incoming request on the localhost server. In my case, this quickly resolved my issue.

Obviously, the use of this method is not limited to debugging. If you are on the train and have no Internet connection, you can use this approach to develop your app anyway.

**One last tip**: if you use GenyMotion as your emulator, use http://10.0.3.2 as the localhost rerouting address.

---

### Case 2

You Are Using a Device:

A different approach is necessary when you want to avoid using the emulator. However, this solution requires you to be on the same Wi-Fi network:

1. Change the API request endpoint to your computer's local IP address, e.g. http://192.168.0.142
2. Run the app on your device

Once again, all requests should go against the localhost server running on your computer.

Let us know if you have any questions or issues: @futurestud_io

Happy Coding!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to answer my own question when I found out the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the manifest:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```